# Netstat returns strange looking foreign address

Tags: ip-address, netstat

I am trying to understand what this foreign address means in a netstat listing:

```
195.sub-174-227-0.myv
```

When I run netstat, some foreign address don't look like normal IP addresses.  Are these IPv6 addresses, proxy, what...?

```
...
tcp     1231      0 ::ffff:192.168.1.18:https   164.sub-70-192-197.my:34669 CLOSE_WAIT  
tcp        1      0 ::ffff:192.168.1.18:https   83.sub-70-192-196.myv:43300 CLOSE_WAIT  
...
```

I don't know what to make of these.  Please advise

Comment: they are IPv6 connections yes. the '195.sub-174-227-0.myv' is just a DNS host name. I can't say I've ever seen a .myv tld, but .my is Malaysia. ISPs usually use strings like this for automatic DNS registration.

Comment: @FrankThomas  You say Malaysia, but the only connections should be in US.  Does this have any security implications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`::ffff:192.168.1.18` is an [IPv6 Address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address).

`164.sub-70-192-197.my` is a hostname for one of the systems you are connected to.  Somewhere between me and Microsoft.com is `dalsbprj01-ae1.0.rd.dl.cox.net` which you can surmise is a Cox owned device, presumably located in Dallas.